# socketio javascript confusion

Tags: javascript, variables, socket.io

I have seen a few examples of socket.io.js.
On the client side the call to create the connection is always

```
  var socket = io.connect();
```

However, this is just creating a point to a function.
How is this enough without another line calling socket?
Is this not just a variable declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `io.connect()` on the client without any arguments returns the socket object representing the connection. Since it's on the client you don't have to do anything like...

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // do stuff with socket
});
```

...like you do on the server. The server expects many clients to connect to it, but the client only ever connects to one server. On the client

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

...is plenty. You can also pass options to `io.connect()`, such as a different URL to connect to.

```
var socket = io.connect('/my/socket/server/endpoint');
```

Comment: it seems to be the only time the messaging between client and server in socket is one way. There is no call to the server required on the client side. However, everything else requires a call. Is there a hidden call in the background?

Comment: What do you mean? It's not one way. `io.connect()` ***is a call***, to [this function](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js#L41-L72). It connects to the socket.io server and creates a `socket` representing the connection. Then you can attach event handlers to the `socket` to listen for messages from the server (`socket.on('myEvent', function (data) { /* do stuff */ });`) or you can emit events on the `socket` to send data to the server (`socket.emit('stuff', data);`). I'm not understanding what you mean by one-way..

Comment: In the one line, with nothing else- var socket = io.connect(); this just declares a variable, it doesn't actually trigger the 'connect()' function, does it. That is to say, I thought variable declarations to functions in javascript were just pointers to functions and not the initialization of the function

Comment: Yes it does. It triggers the connection to the socket server.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to know when the socket has finished connecting to the server? Because there's a `connect` event for that. `socket.on('connect', function(){ /* do stuff */ });`. The call to `io.connect()` triggers the connection to begin but it is Asynchronous. If you need to know the millisecond that the socket is successfully connected then listen for the `connect` event.

Comment: Or maybe you don't understand that the open&close parenthesis after "connect" in `io.connect()` is a ***call*** to the `connect` function? You'd be assigning a function pointer to the variable if all you did was `var socket = io.connect;`, but when you do `var socket = io.connect();` then you're assigning whatever is returned from the call to `io.connect()` to the `socket` variable. And what is returned is an object representing the socket connection that it triggered. Are you maybe just not used to seeing functions called without any arguments?

Comment: that makes perfect sense. Thanks Alex!

Comment: Haha, glad I could help. Not too relevant now that you seem cleared up, but here's a little [demo](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/OVpYyO?editors=001) in case you're still confused. Notice how the call *without* parenthesis actually assigns the function itself to the variable, whereas *with* the parenthesis it assigns the ***result*** of the call to the variable.